# Как вызвать процедуру в Entity framework с параметром out

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework

В Oracle есть следующая процедура, у которая должна вернуть что-то с типом `table of RUE.ruelib%TYPE`:

```
create or replace package PKG_ADRESSE is

  Type streetsArray is table of RUE.ruelib%TYPE;

  Procedure PROCGETSTREETS(iComnum number, sPattern varchar2, io_list Out streetsArray);

end PKG_ADRESSE; 


create or replace package body PKG_ADRESSE is

function GetStreets(iComnum integer, sPattern varchar2) 
  return streetsArray is
  return_value streetsArray;
  begin

select r.ruelib
    bulk collect into return_value
    from RUE r
    where r.COMNUM = iComnum and r.RUELIB like concat(concat('%',sPattern), '%');
    return return_value;
end;


Procedure PROCGETSTREETS(iComnum integer, sPattern varchar2, io_list Out streetsArray) is
   begin
  io_list := GetStreets(iComnum, sPattern);
 End PROCGETSTREETS;
end PKG_ADRESSE;
```

При импортированни этой процедуры в EF выбираю Return a collection of Scalars => strings. Но вылетает исключение {"ORA-06550: Ligne 1, colonne 8 :\nPLS-00306: номер или тип аргумента неправильный при вызове 'PROCGETSTREETS'\nORA-06550: Ligne 1, colonne 8 :\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored"}

Вызываю так:

```
 context.PKG_ADRESSE_PROCGETSTREETS(7485, "streetPattern");
```

Как ее правильно импортировать в EF ? и как потом вызвать?

**UPDATE:**
Если при импорте не выбирать возврщаемое значение, то EF генерирует следующий код:

```
 public virtual int PKG_ADRESSE_PROCGETSTREETS(Nullable<decimal> iCOMNUM, string sPATTERN)
        {
            var iCOMNUMParameter = iCOMNUM.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("ICOMNUM", iCOMNUM) :
                new ObjectParameter("ICOMNUM", typeof(decimal));

            var sPATTERNParameter = sPATTERN != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("SPATTERN", sPATTERN) :
                new ObjectParameter("SPATTERN", typeof(string));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("PKG_ADRESSE_PROCGETSTREETS", iCOMNUMParameter, sPATTERNParameter);
        }
```

Где `ExecuteFunction` принимает лишь два параметра, вместо трех( имя процедуры не в счет).

Comment: Я не специалист в EF, но что-то мне подсказывает, что при импорте возвращаемое значение у вас должно быть пустое, зато должен быть объявлен третий параметр. И при вызове вы также должны использовать параметр, из которого будете забирать значение. Беглое гугление намекает на то же самое: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896334(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @andreycha, такой подход срабатывает если в базе параметр с типом out простого типа(varchar, number и т.д). А вот когда я обьявил свой тип EF его просто не хочет замечать.